# Subscription validation request failed - Graph API

Tags: azure-functions, microsoft-graph-api, postman

I have one Azure function which I am trying to call from postman, the function is suppose to subscribe to the Graph API. Here's the code of Azure function.

```
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static class getTrigger
    {
        [FunctionName("getTrigger")]
        public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
        {
            log.Info($"C# HTTP trigger function begun");
            string response = string.Empty;
 
            string requestContent = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            log.Info($"Received events: {requestContent}");
 
            if (requestContent == string.Empty || requestContent == "")
            {
                string validationToken = req.GetQueryNameValuePairs()
                .FirstOrDefault(q => string.Compare(q.Key, "validationToken", true) == 0)
                .Value;
 
                if (validationToken != null)
                {
                    //Send success responce for subscription 
                    var token = validationToken;
                    log.Info($"GetQueryNameValuePairs: {validationToken}");
                    return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, validationToken);                   
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //invoke power automate 
                TriggerPowerAutomate(requestContent,log);
            }
            return req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, response);
        }
}
```

[image: ScreenshotOfAzureFunction]

And this is the body I am using in postman to call this function.

```
"changeType": "created",
  "notificationUrl": "https://flowinvokerfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net/api/getTrigger",
  "resource": "/users",
  "expirationDateTime": "2024-12-12T11:30:30.0000000Z",
  "clientState": "SecretClientState"
}
```

[image: Screenshot2]

In return I am getting this response in postman and not sure what to do about it.

[image: Screenshot3]

I am following this blog to achieve my goal: https://vikrantsdynamicsblogs.wordpress.com/2020/05/24/invoke-power-automate-on-creation-of-new-user-in-azure-ad/

The code is same as in the blog, I am not so sure what I am missing here.
Any help of direction would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are getting **Notification endpoint must respond with 200 OK to validate request** error because your function is failing. Before making the Graph API Subscription call, you can execute your function to ensure if you are getting expected output.

I have used the code below to make the Subscription call and getting the expected response.

**Function Code**-

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Graph.Models;

namespace _77845450
{
    public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("GetTrigger")]
        public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
            [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
            ILogger log)
        {
            var validationToken = req.Query["validationToken"];
            log.LogInformation(validationToken);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(validationToken))
            {
                log.LogInformation("validationToken: " + validationToken);
                return new ContentResult { Content = validationToken, ContentType = "text/plain" };
            }

            string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
            var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GraphNotification>(requestBody);

            return new OkResult();
        }
    }

    public class GraphNotification
    {
        public List<ChangeNotification> value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Postman**-

[image]

**References**-

[Graph Change Notification Web Hook with Azure Functions - DEV Community](https://dev.to/425show/graph-change-notification-web-hook-with-azure-functions-l4i).

Comment: With the given code I am seeing these errors. 
https://ibb.co/Cn6wPrs

I am using azure portal to create this function, and the architecture I am using is windows with asp.

Comment: First create it in visual studio and execute it there and then deploy it to function app